# What type of phrase is "done"?

Tags: grammaticality, terminology

Examples are provided aplenty, from chef Gordon Ramsay:

> *Fry. Roast. Drizzle. Done.*
>
> *Drizzle olive into the sauce circling the fish. Done.*

But you also see the term used on buttons in computers and mobile devices - presumably used as a contraction of *I'm done* or *You're done* and frequently displayed as an alternative to *Close*.

But what kind of phrase or grammatical formation would be correct to refer to this usage of the word 'done' as a standalone word. Is it even 'correct' usage, let alone perhaps not even being 'proper' usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Done* is the past participle of *do*. Used alone, it is an effective use of language in the kind of context you describe, but it would not normally be found in formal writing. If you needed a word to describe this kind of usage, *elliptical* would be as good as any.

Comment: So would you class this as an *elliptical imperative sentence*?

Comment: @RogerAttrill: No, I wouldn't. 'Fry', 'roast' and 'drizzle' are imperatives, but 'done' isn't. A useful term for any sentence that doesn't contain a finite verb is 'minor  sentence'.

Answer (score 4):

Gordon Ramsey is notorious for expressing processes as a list of single words. He probably does it to sound dramatic and liven up the mundanity of most cooking exercises. In this case, "Done." is used in place of "The task is complete."

Comment: Yes - but I'm specifically asking *What type of phrase would you call the single word *Done* when used standalone like this. For example would it be classed as an *Imperative Sentence*?

Comment: No. It certainly wouldn't be imperative.
In fact, it's not a sentence; it's a **sentence fragment**, with the rest of whatever sentence it might represent (_You're done_, _I'm done_, _It's done_, etc.) simply not there. 
So if you want to call it a sentence of any kind, you have to show what the rest of the sentence actually is.